# Building / Merging character array pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, character

I'm very new to C++ (coming from C#) and it's giving me puzzles :S

I have a very basic question about arrays and it's pointers.

So if I have the following code:

```
char * test1 = "com";
char * test2 = "ment";
```

I found similar code in some files already. I don't exactly understand how a string can fit in  one character.. but ok...

However, how could I connect these arrays so that I get `"comment"` ?

I'm pretty sure this `char * result = test1 + test2;` would only increase the pointer which would then point to something in the memory, which I dont intend to use.

So is it possible to get an array like `char array[] = {'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't'};` back from this?

or can I at least get a pointer which points to something like `comment\NUL` in the memory?

Comment: A string doesn't fit into one `char`. `"com"` is an array. `test1` is a pointer to the first element of that array. Normally the way you'd do this in C++ is to make them `std::string` and use `test1 + test2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, pointer arithmetic can't solve this.

If you want to have a C-string as the result, allocating space for the whole new string is required, then copying over the characters, typically using `strcat` / `strncat`, but they are C-style string operations.

```
// Your C-strings
const char *test1 = "com";
const char *test2 = "ment";

// Dynamic allocation of memory for result string
char *result = new char[strlen(test1) + strlen(test2) + 1];

// Start with the empty string
*result = '\0';
// Concatenate both input strings (use strncat if you don't know
// for sure that they will fit into the result array!)
strcat(result, test1);
strcat(result, test2);

// (use result pointer)

// Free the memory after last usage
delete[] result;
```

In C++, you typically try to avoid them and use `std::string` instead. Even if you want a C-string as the result, you can use a temporary `std::string` for allocation and management of the required memory as well as for performing the concatenation:

```
// Your C-strings
const char *test1 = "com";
const char *test2 = "ment";

// Wrap in temporary C++ strings and concatenate:
std::string result = std::string(test1) + std::string(test2);

// Get the pointer (only valid as long as result is in scope!)
const char *ptr = result.c_str();
```

Furthermore, please note that you should not assign a string literal to a non-const `char *` pointer, use a `const char*` pointer instead. And try to avoid dealing with raw C-strings as long as possible; of course when you use C libraries you have to use them a lot.

Note also that above mentioned methods are performed at runtime; you can't get a compile-time solution for concatenating two string literals, even though the compiler *could* know what you want to have. I don't know your context, but maybe you only want to have a multi-line string literal, then simply drop the `+` and write `"com" "ment"`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works great so far. However by calling a method wich takes a const char * as parameter causes the error C2664 cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char*' to 'char *'. I used const char * ptr = result.c_str(); before but it still is a char * and not a const char * to the compiler. Can you think of any solution for that?

Comment: Does the method modify the string contents? Then you can't use `c_str`, however if the method doesn't modify it, you can cast away the const-ness with `const_cast<char*>(result.c_str())` However, modifying the characters will then lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A c style solution can be found in the following link:
     http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5681/:

```
int len = strlen(test1)+strlen(test2);
char* result = new char[len +1]; // +1 for null terminated string
snprintf(result,len +1, "%s%s",test1,test2);
result[len] = NULL; 
// use result
delete(result);
```

Comment: Add `1` to the size (for terminating zero). And please at least mention that the memory needs to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize std::string:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Note: the character literals are const (non const is deprecated)!
    const char * test1 = "com";
    const char * test2 = "ment";

    // This gives a compiler error (there is no way to add pointers)
    // const char * concat = test1 + test2;

    // A std::string has an overload for the operator +:
    std::string comment = std::string(test1) + test2;

    // The dynamically allocated string.
    // Note: as soon as the comment string gets altered or destroyed the 
    // pointer s to the internal string data (may) become invalid.
    const char* s = comment.c_str();
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```